# Get multiple voice responses within the same call with TWILIO using the gather verb

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

## Overview

I'm trying to make a survey with multiple questions where the response will be provided by speech and has to be transcribed to text and sent to a webhook, for later processing.

## Problem

All 3 questions are reproduced, but once one of them is answered the call ends and just 1 response is sent to the webhook instead of all 3

I tried the following code in JS

```
const audioFiles = [
  { url: 'https://twilioaudiohcp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/1.mp3', question: 'Q1' },
  { url: 'https://twilioaudiohcp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/2.mp3', question: 'Q2' },
  { url: 'https://twilioaudiohcp.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/3.mp3', question: 'Q3' },
];


const webhookEndpoint = 'webhook'; 


const phoneNumberList = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('test.json', 'utf8')).map(item => item.celular);


const makeCalls = async () => {
  let callCount = 0;


  for (const phoneNumber of phoneNumberList) {
    if (callCount >= 40) {
     
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
      callCount = 0;
    }

    const response = new twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  
    for (const audioFile of audioFiles) {
      // Play the audio
      response.play(audioFile.url);
      response.say(audioFile.question, { voice: 'alice', language: 'es-MX' });

      response.gather({
        input: 'speech',
        language: 'es-MX',
        action: webhookEndpoint,
        speechtimeout: 1,
        method: 'POST',
      });

     

     
      response.pause({ length: 1 });
    }



    const twiml = response.toString();

   
    await client.calls.create({
      twiml: twiml,
      from: fromPhoneNumber,
      to: `+52${phoneNumber}`,
      record: true,
      transcribe: true,
      language: 'es-MX',
    })
      .then(call => {
        console.log('Call initiated:', call.sid);
        callCount++;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('Failed to make the call:', error);
      });
  }
};

makeCalls()
  .then(() => console.log('All calls completed.'))
  .catch(error => console.error('An error occurred:', error));
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a multi-question survey where each response is transcribed and sent to your webhook, you will need to **chain the questions so that they are asked sequentially** rather than all at once within the same call.

In your current setup, all questions are being asked within a single TwiML reponse, and as a result, when the first `<Gather>` receives input, it processes that input and ends without waiting for other responses.

To fix this, try using the `action` attribute of the `<Gather>` verb, which allows you to specify a URL to which Twilio will send the data once the `<Gather>` input is received. You can then respond to that webhook with TwiML to ask the next question.

Here is a conceptual example of how you can set up your TwiML application to ask one question at a time:

1. Ask the first question and use the `action` URL to point to a route where you will handle the response and ask the subsequent question.
2. When the caller responds to the first question, Twilio will send the collected speech input to the `action` URL. In that route on your server-side, you will process the first answer and then return TwiML to ask the second question.
3. Repeat this process for each question in the survey.